# clauses for the same predicate should be grouped

Tags: turbo-prolog

Here I want to make a prolog implementation that will generate the list of permutations of n,n+1,...2*n-1, having the absolute difference between 2 consecutive values <=2.
Ex: for `n=4` the list on which I make the permutations would be `[4,5,6,7]` , a valid permutation would be `[5,4,6,7]` and not a valid one would be `[7,4,6,5]` because `7-4 is 3` . The problem is that I get the following error `clauses for the same predicate should be grouped`. I don't understand what I did wrong..Please help me

```
domains
    el=integer
    list=el*
    lista=list*
predicates
    perm(list,list)
    permutations(integer,list)
    delete(integer,list,list)
    generate(integer,lista)
    create(integer,list)
    create_list(integer,integer,list)
    permutations_aux(integer,list)
    diff(list,integer).
clauses
    create(N,L):-
        M = 2*N,
        create_list(N,M,L).

    create_list(N,M,[N|R]):-
        N<M,
        N1=N+1,
        create_list(N1,M,R).

    create_list(M,M,[]).

    perm([],[]).
    perm(Y,[A|X]):-
        delete(A,Y,Y1),
        perm(Y1,X).

    delete(A,[A|X],X).
    delete(A,[B|X],[B|Y]):-
        delete(A,X,Y).

    permutations(N,X):-
        create(N,X1),
        perm(X1,X).
        diff(X,2).

    permutations_aux(N,X):-
        permutations(N,X).

    diff([],_).
    diff([_],_).
    diff([X,Y|T],M):-
        abs(Y-X) <=M,!,
        diff([Y|T],M).

    generate(N,R):-
        findall(X,permutations_aux(N,X),R).


goal
generate(4,P),
write(P).
```

Comment: Oh I can't belive . How stupid I am.. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I've done it a few times. Now that you've seen that error, it will be one of the first things you check. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error or warning:

```
Clauses for the same predicate should be grouped
```

Means that you have interleaved definition of different clauses. In other words, clauses for a predicate with the same name should all be defined together in a group. Such as:

```
foo(X) :-
    some stuff
foo(Y) :-
    some stuff

bar(X) :-
    some stuff
bar(Y) :-
    some stuff
```

You will get the warning/error if you do:

```
foo(X) :-
    some stuff

bar(X) :-
    some stuff

foo(Y) :-
    some stuff

bar(Y) :-
    some stuff
```

Your error is that you have a period after `perm(X1,X).` in your `permutations` clause. It should be a comma:

```
permutations(N,X):-
    create(N,X1),
    perm(X1,X).      <--- Error here
    diff(X,2).

permutations_aux(N,X):-
    permutations(N,X).

diff([],_).
```

So it really thinks you have:

```
permutations(N,X):-
    create(N,X1),
    perm(X1,X).

diff(X,2).

permutations_aux(N,X):-
    permutations(N,X).

diff([],_).
```

Which is an interleave of definitions for `diff`.